# Unmarshall XML RPC from its value

Tags: go, struct

I am having some problem trying to unmarshall XMLRPC into Go Struct

The data I want to unmarshall is structured like this:

```
rawXMLData := `<methodResponse>
    <params>
    <param>
 <value>
   <struct>
     <member>
       <name>RESPONSECODE</name>
       <value><string>68</string></value>
     </member>
     <member>
       <name>REQUESTID</name>
       <value><string>120001</string></value>
     </member>
     <member>
       <name>MESSAGE</name>
       <value><string>Currently Unavailable, Please try again later </string></value>
     </member>
     <member>
       <name>TRANSACTIONID</name>
       <value><string>271231425</string></value>
     </member>
   </struct>
 </value>
    </param>
    </params>
 </methodResponse>
`
```

and I'm trying to put the data into this struct

```
type Response struct {
    RESPONSECODE  string `xml:RESPONSECODE`
    REQUESTID     string `xml:REQUESTID`
    MESSAGE       string `xml:MESSAGE`
    TRANSACTIONID string `xml:TRANSACTIONID`
}
```

But it doesn't work, when I tried to unmarshall it with

```
val := Response{}
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(rawXMLData), &val)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
fmt.Println("val = ", val)

//in terminal
//val = {  }
```

The value that need to be taken were `<name>` and `<value>`, that represent the label and its value (in corresponding golang struct).
I think the problem was because the field label (for the golang struct) is inside the xmltag value, and not the xmltag itself. And I haven't found any clue on how to access this value.

Currently I tried a new struct like this, then tried to manually parse the array into the struct.

```
type Member struct {
    Name  string `xml:"name"`
    Value string `xml:"value>string"`
}

type Resps struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"methodResponse"`
    Members []Member `xml:"params>param>value>struct>member"`
}
```

and manage to get this

```
    value := Resps{}
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(rawXMLData), &value)
    fmt.Println(value.Members)
// terminal result:
// [{RESPONSECODE 68} {REQUESTID 120001} {MESSAGE Currently Unavailable, Please try again later} //{TRANSACTIONID 271231425}]
//
// then put each of the value.Members into corresponding struct field
```

Are there any other solution to directly take the rawXML data into the first struct?
or do we need to parse it in two step like I did?

Comment: *"Are there any other solution to directly take the rawXML data into the first struct?"* -- No, there aren't. You could make it "easier to use" by implementing the `xml.Unmarshaler` interface but that may require a bit more code than your original solution.